# How to bind mount a directory from the client side?

Tags: docker

The most typical scenario is that the client system is a windows, thus the linux containers are running in some virtual machine, most likely in a WSL2.

However, as I experienced, bind mounts into the docker containers (that `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path` thing) mount directories always on the system of the docker**d**. Thus, I could not find a way to mount a directory on the side of the client, which is a problem if they are different.

Is the any easy way to that, except the braindamaged idea of synchrozing everything into the remote container before a run?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Although it would easily possible to inject some filesharing RPC mechanism into the docker client, and sharing the local fs on the client-server channel, somehow no one thought on it.

Not even the windows pre-packaged docker can do that directly on the docker level. The windows docker is the package of a docker client, a WSL2 instance and a dockerd on this WSL2 instance. There the GUI has to set up some "shared drives" functionality, which some unknown file sharing mechanism between the WSL2 dockerd and the windows filesystem.

Thus, the only way to achieve this if there is some (from the docker.exe - dockerd independent) filesharing from the client into the server.

Comment: If I overlooked something and the post is still not closed, I would happily give the accept to better answers.